# What is the best locator for the below tag?

Tags: protractor

Below is the tag for a password field in Login form.

Our guys used the same class name for EMail field also. Hence I cannot use className for password to locate it in protractor, since xpath and css(id design changes) are not reliable, what is the best option for me?

Tag for Email field:

```
<input class="native-input sc-ion-input-md" aria-labelledby="ion-input-0-lbl" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" name="ion-input-0" placeholder="" required="" type="email">
```

Tag for password field:

```
<input class="native-input sc-ion-input-md" aria-labelledby="ion-input-5-lbl" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" name="ion-input-5" placeholder="" required="" type="password">
```

For submit button:

```
<ion-button _ngcontent-rbh-c129="" type="submit" color="loginbutton ion-margin" class="ion-color ion-color-loginbutton ion-margin md button button-solid ion-activatable ion-focusable hydrated">Login</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t suggest you to go with `ion-input` properties since it’s Ionic related properties generated during the build process and it can be dynamic.

Use `type` instead since it is:

- Obvious
- Static

```
input[type="email"]
```

And

```
input[type="password"]
```

After some time you will have hard time understanding your own code and trying to recall what `ion-input-0`
 refers to.

Comment: Thank you. That helped me to sendKeys into the field. Now I used the same kind of Css selector for Login button and now its throwing an error. I will add the code in the question to make it easy for you.

let loginbutton = element(by.css('input[type="submit"]'))

Comment: Sorry, I get it. I removed the word Input since it is not an input field and it worked fine.. Is that correct?

Comment: @SaiKrishnaPulivarthi you got the point. You will need `ion-button[type="submit"]`

Comment: Thank you! I understood!

Answer (score 0):

By css:

```
element(By.css('input[name="ion-input-0"][type="email"]')),
```

and:

```
 element(By.css('input[name="ion-input-5"][type="password"]')),
```

Comment: I just looked at the code from other pages, its all same as above? Is it okay for me to automate the entire project based on CSS? Sorry I am a newbie.

Comment: I tried the suggestion and it threw an error. Message:
    Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, input[name="ion-input-0"][type="email"])

Comment: @SaiKrishnaPulivarthi Put some wait, it is possible the element to be not displayed yet and the tool wants to click it.

Comment: Please don't mind if I am wrong. I am using Protractor and I have heard that Protractor wait for the element automatically and there is no need to make the driver wait manually.

Comment: @SaiKrishnaPulivarthi it is customized for angular, but anyway you need waits. Before you click on do any action you need to be sure that element is displayed:

Comment: Thank you. I understood!